# Github Checks API and Check Suites

Tags: github, github-api

Lately, I have been working with github checks API and trying to implement check runs and check suites concept using https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/guides/creating-ci-tests-with-the-checks-api.
I am stuck with few questions:

1. Whenever I create a commit, no of check runs event generated and no of check suite events generated always varies, meaning

commit1:

check suite1- event requested (present and last commit)(event id is different)

check run1- created (sha commit of head)

check run2- completed (sha commit of head)

event ids are same for both checkrun1 and checkrun2

check suite2- event completed (event id is different)

commit4: 4 check suites and 6 check runs

PR: 2 check suites and  4 check runs events generated

As per my understanding, check runs are associated with the sha of the change and at each commit on branch check suite is created so why there are more than one check runs with different event ids are created for one commit and why always the check suites events ids dont match?

Can anyone help me in understanding this?